# Return the n best 2-person selections with salary constraints using Python SciPy Minimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a list of skill levels and salaries and am trying to select the most optimal 2 selections to maximize skill while keeping under a total salary.  Using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, I am able to get the most optimal selection with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define the individuals' skill levels and salaries
skill_levels = np.array([7, 13, 5, 1, 11])
salaries = np.array([15,  8,  9, 12, 10])

# Objective function for maximizing total skill level
def objective(selection):
    return -np.sum(skill_levels * selection)

# Total salary constraint (no more than $20)
def salary_constraint(selection):
    return 20 - np.sum(salaries * selection)

# Number of players selected constraint (select exactly 2 players)
def num_selection_constraint(selection):
    return np.sum(selection) - 2

# Bounds are either 1 or 0 (selected or not-selected)
bounds = [(0, 1)] * len(skill_levels)

# Set the constraints based on the above functions
constraints = [
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': salary_constraint},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': num_selection_constraint}
]

# Start by guessing the first 2 people
x0 = np.zeros(len(skill_levels))
x0[:2] = 1

# Plug into minimize function
result = minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

# Retrieve the optimal solution
optimal_selection = result.x
selected_indices = np.where(optimal_selection > 0.5)[0]

selected_indices
"""Returns
array([1, 4])
"""
```

**I am now looking for the next *n* best unique selections.**

- I've tried tracking each previous selection and adding it to the constraints, but this increases the runtime exponentially and doesn't work as expected:

```py
def repeat_selection_constraint(selection, iter):
    return 5 - selection * prev_selection[iter]

# Initialize previous selection
prev_selection = np.zeros((num_selections, len(skill_levels)))
for i in range(num_selections):
    # Define the constraints
    constraints = [
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': salary_constraint},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': num_selection_constraint},
        *[{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: repeat_selection_constraint(x, lup)} for lup in range(i+1)]
    ]
```

- I've also considered retrieving all combinations using `itertools.combinations` and running `scipy.optimize.minimize` on each, but that is also time prohibitive.

**NOTE:** my actual use case is considerably larger than this sample; therefore, I'm interested in an elegant solution to this problem that can reasonably scale to 10^3 persons.

Comment: Everything I see here is linear, so this seems like a better job for a classical linear program with an assignment vector.

Comment: Unless _n_ is significant. How big will it be?

Comment: For a given total skill level solution, there may be multiple skill vectors. Is it important that you see every one, or is it acceptable to see only one skill vector per skill total?

Comment: @Reinderien, _n_ is going to be <20. It is important to see each skill vector (meaning each 2-person selection needs to be tracked)

Comment: Then you'll want an outer LP step and an inner diophantine step. I can demonstrate this in an hour or two

Comment: what does `result` look like?  Is `result.x`  an array of floats, without a clear "2 best"?

Comment: Just to help us better visualize the result, `result.x` is `[ 7.772e-16  1.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  1.000e+00]`.  2 values are close to 1, the others 0.

Comment: Right @hpaulj, that's the most optimal result. What's the next best result?

Comment: @hpaulj Not really, though you're going in the right direction. Instead of turning off a skill, you have an outer loop where the total skill level is given an incrementally lower constraint.

Answer (score 1):

A single linear program won't do it, because you need multiple solutions.

If you had less than (say) 30 player variables, you could do iterative-LP where you put the binary assignments for each player in a dot-product with powers of 2 to produce a canonical order numeral, incrementally narrowing the canonical order constraint to search for more answers in sequence. However, for high variable counts this will run into precision problems and stop working.

Here is a solution that still uses iterative LP. I had initially guessed that the inner solution search could use a stock Diophantine solver, but it can't because the variables are bounded (binary). Instead, I show a method where the inner increment is a bisection search. Please test this thoroughly because I haven't.

```py
from itertools import islice
from typing import Any, NamedTuple, Iterator

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint


class Problem(NamedTuple):
    skill_levels: np.ndarray
    salaries: np.ndarray
    max_salary: int = 20
    n_players: int = 2

    @classmethod
    def default_setup(cls) -> 'Problem':
        skill_levels = np.array([7, 13, 5, 1, 11])
        salaries = np.array([15,  8,  9, 12, 10])
        order = skill_levels.argsort()
        return cls(
            skill_levels=skill_levels[order],
            salaries=salaries[order],
        )

    @classmethod
    def big_setup(cls, m: int = 100_000) -> 'Problem':
        rand = default_rng(seed=0)
        skill_levels = rand.integers(low=1, high=20, size=m)
        salaries = rand.integers(low=1, high=20, size=m)
        order = skill_levels.argsort()
        return cls(
            skill_levels=skill_levels[order],
            salaries=salaries[order],
        )

    @property
    def n(self) -> int:
        return self.skill_levels.size

    @property
    def max_skill_level(self) -> float:
        return self.skill_levels.sum() + 0.5


def setup_milp(prob: Problem) -> tuple[
    dict[str, Any],  # milp kwargs
    LinearConstraint,  # skill sum constraint
]:
    skill_sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(A=prob.skill_levels, ub=prob.max_skill_level)

    return {
        # Maximize selected skill level
        'c': -prob.skill_levels,
        # Decision variables are integral
        'integrality': np.ones_like(prob.skill_levels, dtype=bool),
        # Decision variables are binary
        'bounds': (0, 1),

        'constraints': (
            # Exactly two players must be selected
            LinearConstraint(A=np.ones_like(prob.skill_levels), lb=prob.n_players, ub=prob.n_players),
            # Apply a fixed maximum salary
            LinearConstraint(A=prob.salaries, ub=prob.max_salary),
            # Evolving maximum for skill sum
            skill_sum_constraint,
        ),
    }, skill_sum_constraint


def outer_lp(milp_params: dict[str, Any], skill_sum_constraint: LinearConstraint) -> Iterator[int]:
    while True:
        res = milp(**milp_params)
        if not res.success:
            break
        skill_total = -round(res.fun)

        # res.x is one solution, but we ignore it and use the knowledge that skill_total produces at
        # least one solution.
        yield skill_total

        # ub is a read-only array, so replace it
        skill_sum_constraint.ub = np.array((skill_total - 0.5,), dtype=skill_sum_constraint.ub.dtype)


def log_traversal(prob: Problem, skill_total: int) -> Iterator[list[int]]:
    # for simplicity, hard-coded to two players
    first_limit = prob.n

    while True:
        first_idx = prob.skill_levels[:first_limit].searchsorted(skill_total)
        if first_idx >= first_limit:
            first_idx -= 1  # too high; use highest available
        first_limit = first_idx
        first_total = skill_total - prob.skill_levels[first_idx]

        second_idx = prob.skill_levels[:first_idx].searchsorted(first_total)
        if second_idx < first_idx:
            second_value = prob.skill_levels[second_idx]
            second_total = first_total - second_value
            if second_total == 0:
                # Handle duplicate values
                second_idx_arr, = (prob.skill_levels == second_value).nonzero()
                first_idx_arr = np.full_like(second_idx_arr, fill_value=first_idx)
                salary = prob.salaries[first_idx_arr] + prob.salaries[second_idx_arr]
                results = np.vstack((first_idx_arr, second_idx_arr))
                no_overlap = (first_idx_arr != second_idx_arr) & (salary <= prob.max_salary)
                salary = salary[no_overlap]
                results = results[:, no_overlap][:, salary.argsort()].T
                yield from results
        else:
            # if the second index needs to be higher than we can allow, there are no more solutions
            break


def all_solutions(prob: Problem) -> Iterator[tuple[
    int,  # skill total
    int,  # salary total
    list[int],  # player indices
]]:
    milp_params, skill_sum_constraint = setup_milp(prob)

    for skill_total in outer_lp(milp_params, skill_sum_constraint):
        for players in log_traversal(prob, skill_total):
            assert prob.skill_levels[players].sum() == skill_total
            yield skill_total, prob.salaries[players].sum(), players


def main() -> None:
    prob = Problem.big_setup()

    print('Skill, salary, assignments:')
    for skill, salary, players in islice(all_solutions(prob), 20):
        print(skill, salary, players)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With original data this outputs

```
Skill, salary, assignments:
24 18 [4 3]
18 17 [4 1]
16 19 [3 1]
14 20 [4 0]
```

Testing this with the larger arrays shown in the code this outputs

```
Skill, salary, assignments:
38 12 [499999 497627]
38 12 [499999 475402]
38 12 [499999 492837]
38 12 [499999 484121]
38 12 [499999 486641]
38 12 [499999 479932]
38 12 [499999 494208]
38 12 [499999 486656]
38 12 [499999 496272]
38 12 [499999 494895]
38 12 [499999 486661]
38 12 [499999 475371]
38 12 [499999 484098]
38 12 [499999 489454]
38 12 [499999 475366]
38 12 [499999 475364]
38 12 [499999 475362]
38 12 [499999 496243]
38 12 [499999 480804]
38 12 [499999 486675]
```

in one second for n=20 records. I haven't been very careful with micro-optimization especially around the duplicate stuff so that could get faster.

### The remix

For 1,000 players or less, it doesn't make much sense to go through all the trouble of bisection searching for pairs, etc. Change the design so that the salary and skill matrices are kept as broadcast sums (which still only occupy on the order of 4 MB each for 1000 elements to the side). And add a second loop level to the LP so that it naturally optimizes skill first and salary second. This approach requires that both skill and talent have discrete steps.

```py
from itertools import islice
from typing import Any, NamedTuple, Iterator

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint


class Problem(NamedTuple):
    skill_levels: np.ndarray
    salaries: np.ndarray
    skill_combos: np.ndarray   # for simplicity, hard-coded to two players
    salary_combos: np.ndarray
    max_salary: int = 20
    n_players: int = 2

    @classmethod
    def default_setup(cls) -> 'Problem':
        skill_levels = np.array([7, 13, 5, 1, 11])
        salaries = np.array([15,  8,  9, 12, 10])
        return cls.with_arrays(skill_levels, salaries)

    @classmethod
    def big_setup(cls, m: int = 1_000) -> 'Problem':
        rand = default_rng(seed=0)
        skill_levels = rand.integers(low=1, high=20, size=m)
        salaries = rand.integers(low=1, high=20, size=m)
        return cls.with_arrays(skill_levels, salaries)

    @classmethod
    def with_arrays(cls, skill: np.ndarray, salary: np.ndarray) -> 'Problem':
        return cls(
            skill_levels=skill,
            salaries=salary,
            skill_combos=np.tril(np.add.outer(skill, skill), k=-1),
            salary_combos=np.tril(np.add.outer(salary, salary), k=-1),
        )

    @property
    def n(self) -> int:
        return self.skill_levels.size

    @property
    def max_skill_level(self) -> float:
        return self.skill_levels.sum() + 0.5


def setup_milp(prob: Problem) -> tuple[
    dict[str, Any],  # milp kwargs
    LinearConstraint,  # skill sum constraint
    LinearConstraint,  # salary sum constraint
]:
    skill_sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(A=prob.skill_levels, ub=prob.max_skill_level)
    salary_sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(A=prob.salaries, lb=0)

    return {
        # Maximize selected skill level, and with less weight, minimize salary
        # Skill level must be integral for this to work
        'c': prob.salaries/2/prob.max_salary - prob.skill_levels,
        # Decision variables are integral
        'integrality': np.ones_like(prob.skill_levels, dtype=bool),
        # Decision variables are binary
        'bounds': (0, 1),

        'constraints': (
            # Exactly two players must be selected
            LinearConstraint(A=np.ones_like(prob.skill_levels), lb=prob.n_players, ub=prob.n_players),
            # Apply a fixed maximum salary
            LinearConstraint(A=prob.salaries, ub=prob.max_salary),
            # Evolving maximum for skill sum
            skill_sum_constraint,
            # Evolving minimum for salary sum
            salary_sum_constraint,
        ),
    }, skill_sum_constraint, salary_sum_constraint


def outer_lp(
    prob: Problem,
    milp_params: dict[str, Any],
    skill_sum_constraint: LinearConstraint,
    salary_sum_constraint: LinearConstraint,
) -> Iterator[tuple[int, int]]:
    while True:
        # Any salary
        salary_sum_constraint.lb = np.full_like(salary_sum_constraint.lb, 0)
        res = milp(**milp_params)
        if not res.success:
            break
        skill_total = round(prob.skill_levels.dot(res.x))
        salary_total = round(prob.salaries.dot(res.x))
        yield skill_total, salary_total

        # Fixed skill
        skill_sum_constraint.lb = np.full_like(skill_sum_constraint.lb, skill_total)
        skill_sum_constraint.ub = skill_sum_constraint.lb

        while True:
            # Salary floor
            salary_sum_constraint.lb = np.full_like(salary_sum_constraint.lb, salary_total + 0.1)
            res = milp(**milp_params)
            if not res.success:
                break

            salary_total = round(prob.salaries.dot(res.x))
            yield skill_total, salary_total

        # New skill ceiling
        skill_sum_constraint.lb = np.full_like(skill_sum_constraint.lb, 0)
        skill_sum_constraint.ub = np.full_like(skill_sum_constraint.ub, skill_total - 0.1)


def log_traversal(prob: Problem, skill: int, salary: int) -> np.ndarray:
    # for simplicity, hard-coded to two players
    yx = np.vstack((
        (prob.skill_combos == skill) &
        (prob.salary_combos == salary)
    ).nonzero())
    return yx.T


def all_solutions(prob: Problem) -> Iterator[tuple[
    int,  # skill total
    int,  # salary total
    list[int],  # player indices
]]:
    milp_params, skill_sum_constraint, salary_sum_constraint = setup_milp(prob)

    for skill, salary in outer_lp(prob, milp_params, skill_sum_constraint, salary_sum_constraint):
        for players in log_traversal(prob, skill, salary):
            assert prob.skill_levels[players].sum() == skill
            assert prob.salaries[players].sum() == salary
            yield skill, salary, players


def main() -> None:
    prob = Problem.big_setup()

    print('Skill, salary, assignments:')
    for skill, salary, players in islice(all_solutions(prob), 20):
        print(skill, salary, players)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Skill, salary, assignments:
38 3 [885 842]
38 4 [842 245]
38 4 [842 557]
38 4 [962 842]
38 5 [842 551]
38 5 [842 559]
38 5 [842 636]
38 5 [885 245]
38 5 [885 557]
38 5 [962 885]
38 6 [557 245]
38 6 [842 277]
38 6 [842 355]
38 6 [842 514]
38 6 [842 638]
38 6 [885 551]
38 6 [885 559]
38 6 [885 636]
38 6 [962 245]
38 6 [962 557]
```